# Checking a square of numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
square([A1, A2, A3|_], [B1, B2, B3|_], [C1, C2, C3|_]):-
    all_diff([A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3]).
squares([[]|_]):- !.
squares([[A1,A2,A3|A4], [B1,B2,B3|B4], [C1,C2,C3|C4], [D1,D2,D3|D4], [E1,E2,E3|E4], [F1,F2,F3|F4], [G1,G2,G3|G4], [H1,H2,H3|H4], [I1,I2,I3|I4]]):-
    square([[A1,A2,A3], [B1,B2,B3], [C1,C2,C3]]),
    square([[D1,D2,D3], [E1,E2,E3], [F1,F2,F3]]),
    square([[G1,G2,G3], [H1,H2,H3], [I1,I2,I3]]),
    squares([A4, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4, I4]).
```

I'm getting a `uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,square/1),squares/1)` - I'm new to Prolog so I'm not quite sure what this is saying (well, where it's saying it's going wrong).

This is inside a sudoku program, by the way.

squares iterates through the 3x3 squares of the sudoku puzzle starting with the top left, middle left, and bottom left - moving to the top middle, middle middle, bottom middle, and so on.

square checks the focus square - A1, A2, A3 are the first three values of the first row
B1, B2, B3 are the first three values of the second row, and so on. It assembles them into one array and checks to make sure they are all different.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between square & squares?  And while you're at it, explain (maybe even with comments?) just how this is trying to do whatever it is trying to do?

Comment: I've added to my question, does that clear things up?

Answer (score 2):

on the lines

```
square([[A1,A2,A3], [B1,B2,B3], [C1,C2,C3]]),
square([[D1,D2,D3], [E1,E2,E3], [F1,F2,F3]]),
square([[G1,G2,G3], [H1,H2,H3], [I1,I2,I3]]),
```

you'll note that the type is ([[],[],[]]), however, the function, square is ([],[],[]).

Changing the lines to

```
square([A1,A2,A3], [B1,B2,B3], [C1,C2,C3]),
square([D1,D2,D3], [E1,E2,E3], [F1,F2,F3]),
square([G1,G2,G3], [H1,H2,H3], [I1,I2,I3]),
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Indeed, what you've run into here is that `square/1` and `square/3` are not the same predicate in Prolog. The name *and* the arity are needed to uniquely identify predicates, so when you get an error about a missing predicate you are sure you have, this sort of thing is almost always the real problem.

Comment: @DanielLyons ahhhh, I wasn't quite sure what the /1 meant but as I understand it means the number of arguments (?) - a big part of knowing what's going on is understanding the error statement and I must say, I didn't.